# MySQL Multiple triggers - Ends the code after one trigger

Tags: mysql, laravel, triggers

I have an application that stores customers data.

I have to make sure that the insertion of customer in one table say t1 in database say d1 should insert the same in table t1 of database d2.

Customer data is linked with three different tables: company, customer and address.

So, I have written three triggers one for company table, one for customer and the last for address table. When I run the code, the first trigger works. Then the running code has stopped and showed me a blank page in laravel.

I checked in different ways and found out that the code stopped stopped after one trigger in database.

How can I solve this?

My trigger code is as follows:

```
    DELIMITER &&

create trigger after_insert_ecatalog_company after insert on `ecatalog`.company for each row begin insert into `eRetailer`.company(id, code, name, is_active, created_at, updated_at) values (NEW.id, NEW.code, NEW.name, NEW.is_active, NEW.created_at, NEW.updated_at); END&&

DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER &&

create trigger after_insert_ecatalog_customer after insert on `ecatalog`.customer for each row begin insert into `eRetailer`.customer(id, store_id, company_id, customer_type_id, email, username, phone, srepemail, srepecode, password, firstname, lastname, salesrep_name, salesrep_email, is_active, is_password_changed, remember_token, created_at, updated_at, role) values (NEW.id, NEW.store_id, NEW.company_id, NEW.customer_type_id, NEW.email, NEW.username, NEW.phone, NEW.srepemail, NEW.srepecode, NEW.password, NEW.firstname, NEW.lastname, NEW.salesrep_name, NEW.salesrep_email, NEW.is_active, NEW.is_password_changed, NEW.remember_token, NEW.created_at, NEW.updated_at, NEW.role); END&&

DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER &&

create trigger after_insert_ecatalog_address after insert on `ecatalog`.address for each row begin insert into `eRetailer`.address(id, customer_id, address_type, name, addr1, addr2, city, state, zip, phone, email, code, shipvia, created_at, updated_at, billtocompany, shiptocompany, shiptocountry) values (NEW.id, NEW.customer_id, NEW.address_type, NEW.name, NEW.addr1, NEW.addr2, NEW.city, NEW.state, NEW.zip, NEW.phone, NEW.email, NEW.code, NEW.shipvia, NEW.created_at, NEW.updated_at, NEW.billtocompany, NEW.shiptocompany, NEW.shiptocountry); END&&

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: There are unfortunately a lot of things that might be incorrect here, and without knowing the error message, we can only guess (as it might also just be a bug in your laravel code), so please get and add any errors to your question. To get those errors, you may want to try e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36211515/6248528) or similar; if it is an sql problem, you can also try to insert the data directly (e.g. using the mysql client or phpmyadmin) by running the same queries that laravel does (if you can figure out which they are).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I debugged it. The issue is "PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1442 Can't update table 'company' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger. in /home/vagrant/aurora/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:390". If i insert in db1.t1, it should trigger in db2.t1. Same should happen viceversa. the problem arises in viceversa. When I have trigger in one database, function works normally. When I have trigger in both the database, it shows the error

Comment: Yes, in that case, the vice versa is the problem. Laravel inserts to t1, the trigger on t1 inserts to t2, the trigger on t2 inserts to t1, the trigger on t1 inserts to t2, ... you get the idea. The technical way MySQL prevents this loop is to disallow you from doing anymore changes to the original table, thus the error message. See e.g. [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/42007) for a way around this (there are other options, like replication, dummy columns or letting the app do both inserts). You may want to ask another question on how to properly sync 2 tables vice versa.

Comment: Thanks. I look into the things what you have said. As you said I postes an another question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52763372/synchronize-vice-versa-on-two-database-triggers-mysql). Please have a look.

Comment: Sorry, I may have been a bit unprecise: you should of course first look into the linked question, try it out and test if it works for you (as it seems to do exactly what you are trying, so you would not have to change anything in your other code); then maybe add to your question why it doesn't work for you, or e.g. explain that you tested it, and ask if there are better options because of this or that reservation you have with the solution. Otherwise "check this answer from this link" (and probably a close request for duplicates) is a valid response to that new question.

Comment: Thank you so much @Solarflare. I have tried out the things that is given in the link you shared. Awesome. I have done with it.